# Unable to disable tab bar item via IBAction

Tags: swift

I have a small app that has a Tab bar controller with three tabs. They are all enabled by default. When a certain function is called via IBAction in two of the View Controllers used by the tab bar controller, I want to disable some tab bar items until the function is complete.

Example:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabViewController") as! UITabBarController
viewController.tabBar.items?[0].isEnabled = false
viewController.tabBar.items?[1].isEnabled = false
```

but it is just not working. I confirmed that the tabbar items are valid. For example I can call `print(viewController.tabBar.items?[0].title` and it returns the proper name but setting the isEnable to false doesn't disable it.

I tried doing the same on two of the three tabs but it doesn't work on either.

I can disable them programatically in the TabViewController viewDidLoad using something like;

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let items = self.tabBar.items!
            if items.count > 0 {
                 items[1].isEnabled = false
            }
        }
```

but I want to be able to enable and disable on command.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Make sure `viewController.tabBar.items` is not `nil` otherwise your optional chaining will fail silently

Comment: The code you posted looks like it is creating another instance of your tab view controller and changing its tab bar items. That won’t work. You need to operate on your existing tab bar controller.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I think you may be onto something......

Comment: @LeoDabus I am able to access the Tab names so the items are not nil for sure.

Answer (score 0):

@GeoffHackworth pointed me in the right direction. Instead of accessing existing TabBarController I was instantiating a new one.
That would explain why I could still see the correct items, it just wasn't the  right tabbar.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need this line - `let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabViewController") as! UITabBarController`

You can directly access tabBar like this - `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].isEnabled = false`

It's working for me.